# Django requests sometimes doesn't contain sessions over SSL

Tags: python, django, session, ssl, web-applications

I'm facing something weird over my Django web app, I'm using sessions over the database to keep track of users sessions, but seems like over SSL these sessions doesn't stick around, I don't have pretty much clues why, but I have evidence on how it happens.

My main problem is, that I have a view that if you are logged in it redirects you to the index, and in the index, if you are not logged in, then in redirects you to the login screen, so what happens here is that after login, the server will redirect me to the index page, but the index will get "None" checking over the session for the logged in parameter, and then, on the login form it check again the session and it actually gets that the user in logged in, so I enter in a infinite redirect loop, and after a while chrome says that the page redirect too much times.

This is my settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for rienpaAdmin project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SecretKey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['lodugo.com', 'www.lodugo.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rienpaAdmin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'lodugo.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'lodugo'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 15552000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=7776000
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=False



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rienpaAdmin.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And this is my views.py

```py
def app_admin(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if (request.session.get('logged_in', False)) is not True:
        authentication = "false"
        if request.method == "POST":
            post: QueryDict = request.POST
            firebase_manager = FirebaseManager()
            result = firebase_manager.user_login(post.get('email'), post.get('password'))
            if result:
                messages.success(request, "Ingreso correcto")
                request.session['firebase_session'] = firebase_manager.save_session()
                authentication = "true"
            elif firebase_manager.error_message == "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND":
                messages.error(request, "Error: Esta cuenta no existe")
            elif firebase_manager.error_message == "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                messages.error(request, "Error: Contraseña incorrecta")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error: Ocurrio un error inesperado," +
                               " por favor intentalo de nuevo")
        return render(request,
                      "main/login.html",
                      context={"auth": authentication})
    return redirect("main:index")

def load_user(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if request.method == "POST":
        firebase_manager = FirebaseManager()
        firebase_manager.load_session(request.session['firebase_session'])
        user_data = firebase_manager.user_data()
        request.session['user_data'] = user_data
        request.session['logged_in'] = 'true'
        return HttpResponse("Done")
    raise Http404

def index(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    chart_ready = "true"
    if request.session.get('logged_in', False) is True:
        user = User()
        user.load_data(request.session['user_data'])
        return render(request, "main/admin_main_screen.html", context={"user": user, "chart_ready": chart_ready})
    return redirect("main:appadmin")

def logout(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if request.method == "POST":
        del request.session['user_data']
        del request.session['logged_in']
        del request.session['firebase_session']
        request.session.clear()
        request.session.flush()
        return HttpResponse("Done")
    raise Http404
```

Where app_admin method is my login form, and the index is my index.

I checked the output of the 'logged_in' key on the session and the output was:

```py
None #First load of the login form
None #Second load over the POST method
None #Result over the Index page after redirected with AJAX
True #Result from login form after being redirected
None #Result from index, not getting the session
True #Result from login again, redirects again to index
None #Result over index, redirects again to login
```

As you can see my project was created on Django 2.2, but I'm using Django 3.0, and I'm also using posgreSQL as database. Over my development server in HTTP this works flawlessly

EDIT: I tested to output another session key, for example, the 'firebase_session' key, and seems like I always get the correct value for that, no matter what, but not the case for 'logged_in', this is a good clue, but still need a hand on figuring out what it happening

EDIT2: I tested not with the session key "user_data" as it is a JSON as the firebase_session key, however, this user_data also comes as None sometimes, only the firebase_session is sticking all the time, I really cannot know why

Comment: `is` is not the the right way to compare values. `if not request.session.get('logged_in'):` would be sufficient in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your correction, however, I just change that and in the first attempt the server redirects me 9 times, the index page still gets None on the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it. Reading carefully the documentation on cache sessions ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions)), you can find a warning which clarifies that cache database sessions and just database sessions are not the same, and also, it has a warning saying that the local cache sessions are not multi-process safe, and not good for production, here is the quote:

> Warning
>
> You should only use cache-based sessions if you’re using the Memcached cache backend. The local-memory cache backend doesn’t retain data long enough to be a good choice, and it’ll be faster to use file or database sessions directly instead of sending everything through the file or database cache backends. Additionally, the local-memory cache backend is NOT multi-process safe, therefore probably not a good choice for production environments.

So thanks to this hint I changed my session type on settings.py from:

```py
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

to

```py
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

And everything worked just perfect. This is without using the memcached backend, which seems to be the best approach for Django as it use the physical memory, I will try that in the future as it is the correct way to use the cached_db backend correctly.